# Converting/splitting and transposing a groupby or datetime object into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, time-series

I have a pandas df:

```
                                Reading
2016-06-01 09:00:00+09:00       1190.958
2016-06-01 10:30:00+09:00       1189.886
2016-06-01 12:00:00+09:00       1194.089
2016-06-01 13:30:00+09:00       1193.464
2016-06-01 15:00:00+09:00       1193.050
2016-06-02 09:00:00+09:00       1190.879
2016-06-02 12:00:00+09:00       1190.025
2016-06-02 13:30:00+09:00       1187.057
2016-06-02 15:00:00+09:00       1186.600
```

I want to transform it like this:

```
           09:00:00+09:00  10:30:00+09:00  12:00:00+09:00  13:30:00+09:00  15:00:00+09:00
2016-06-01 1190.958        1189.886        1194.089        1193.464        1193.050
2016-06-02 1190.879        NA              1190.025        1187.057        1186.600
```

I thought I can group the data by date like this:

```
df.groupby(df.index.values.astype('<M8[D]'))
```

But how do i convert this groupby object into a dataframe with transposed columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reassign your index with date and time of the current index and `unstack`

```
df.index = [df.index.date, df.index.time]
df.Reading.unstack()
```

[image]