# stacking together data from multiple days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Note- it is not a duplicate of [Converting/splitting and transposing a groupby or datetime object into dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922661/converting-splitting-and-transposing-a-groupby-or-datetime-object-into-dataframe)

I have a pandas df:

```
                                Reading
2016-06-01 09:00:00+09:00       1190.958
2016-06-01 10:30:00+09:00       1189.886
2016-06-01 12:00:00+09:00       1194.089
2016-06-01 13:30:00+09:00       1193.464
2016-06-01 15:00:00+09:00       1193.050
2016-06-02 09:00:00+09:00       1190.879
2016-06-02 12:00:00+09:00       1190.025
2016-06-02 13:30:00+09:00       1187.057
2016-06-02 15:00:00+09:00       1186.600
2016-06-03 09:00:00+09:00       1190.879
2016-06-03 10:30:00+09:00       1189.886
2016-06-03 12:00:00+09:00       1190.025
2016-06-03 13:30:00+09:00       1187.057
2016-06-03 15:00:00+09:00       1186.600
```

I want to transform it like this (as an example)

```
           09:00:00+09:00  10:30:00+09:00  12:00:00+09:00  13:30:00+09:00  15:00:00+09:00  09:00:00+09:00  10:30:00+09:00  12:00:00+09:00  13:30:00+09:00  15:00:00+09:00
2016-06-01 1190.958        1189.886        1194.089        1193.464        1193.050        1190.879        NA              1190.025        1187.057        1186.600
2016-06-02 1190.879        NA              1190.025        1187.057        1186.600        1190.958        1189.886        1194.089        1193.464        1193.050
```

So for each day, I need to get previous w days of data (w=2 here) in the row corresponding to each day.

My approach is like this so far:
Using the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922661/converting-splitting-and-transposing-a-groupby-or-datetime-object-into-dataframe) I initially get each day's data in row by doing the following:

```
df.index = [df.index.date, df.index.time]
df= df.unstack()
```

then i concat shifted dataframes along axis=1 using:

```
l=[df.shift(i) for i in np.arange(w)] # list of progressively shifted dataframes
df=pd.concat(l,axis=1) #all shifted dataframes concatenated along axis=1
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting/splitting and transposing a groupby or datetime object into dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922661/converting-splitting-and-transposing-a-groupby-or-datetime-object-into-dataframe)

Comment: Could you elucidate what  you're saying a bit more then. What do you mean by "get previous w" in each row. So you want to add up all the entries from that day and the preceding? What does concat shifted datagrames along axis=1 mean?

Comment: should be clearer now

Answer (score 1):

follow advice from linked question and answer... that's just good question answering :-)

```
df.index = [df.index.date, df.index.time]
d1 = df.Reading.unstack()
d1
```

[image]

then define a new function using `shift` and `pd.concat`

```
def do_n_such_and_such(df, n):
    k = len(df) - n + 1
    shifts = [df.shift(s) for s in range(0, -n, -1)]
    return pd.concat(shifts, axis=1).iloc[:k]

do_n_such_and_such(d1, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: So this is practically the same as what I'm doing except for selecting rows till k, right?  Or did I miss something?

Comment: that's all there is to it.